# How to pass arguments from 'conftest,py' to test file (pytest)?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, conftest

How to pass arguments from `conftest.py` to `test` file ?

**conftest.py**

```
import sys,pytest


def tear_down():
    print("teardown")

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--a1", action="store", default="some_default_value", help="provide a1")
    parser.addoption("--b1", action="store", default=None, help="provide b1")
    parser.addoption("--c1", action="store", default=None, help="provide c1")


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def set_up(request):
    print("set up")

    a1 = request.config.getoption("--a1")
    b1 = request.config.getoption("--b1")
    c1 = request.config.getoption("--c1")

    if not(b1) and not(c1):
        sys.exit("Both values can't be empty")

    if b1 and c1:
        sys.exit("provide either b1 or c1, not both")
```

In `test.py`, I need to access all those arguments `a,b & c`. How can I do that ?

**test.py**

```
import pytest

class Test1:
    def fun1(self,a,b="",c=""):
        print("task1")

    def fun2(self,a,b="",c=""):
        print("task2")

class Test2:
    def fun12(self,a,b="",c=""):
        print("task12")

    def fun34(self, a, b="", c=""):
        print("task34")
```

I'm new to pytest. Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been answered many times already. And you can find it easily in the official documentation [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html). Learn how to search for solutions and read documentations, it's an invaluable skill.

To answer your question, you'd do it like this:

**conftest.py**

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def set_up(request):    
    return {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
```

**test.py**

```py
import pytest

class Test1:
    def test_fun1(self, set_up):
        print("{0} - {1} - {2}".format(set_up["a"], set_up["b"], set_up["c"]))
```

I left out the rest of our example in order to focus on what you missed. I also renamed the test function, because pytest will by default discover only functions that start with `test` as actuall test cases: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#confval-python_functions So unless you change the behaviour in e.g. `pytest.ini`, this function would not be run as a test case.

Comment: Well, one searches on google and this happens to be te first answer :)